# Missing Administrative Templates for Bitlocker

Tags: windows, windows-10, active-directory, bitlocker, windows-server-2016

I have some laptops running 21H2 that we want to encrypt with bitlocker.  The plan is to store the keys in AD.  So I tested it on one computer and it worked.

However, when I went to set up the GPO to roll out, there were different administrative templates.  Whereas on the laptop there were more settings, and a subfolder for Fixed drives, OS drives, and removable drives, the AD server has none of those subfolders, and only limited options in the root of that folder. **The DC is running Server 2016.**

Currently when I enable `Admin templates\Windows Components\Bitlocker Drive Encryption\Turn on Bitlocker backup to Active Directory Domain Services`, it doesn't change any settings on the laptop when I check out `Admin templates\Windows components\Bitlocker Drive Encryption`.  Nothing is configured.

Is this because the templates don't match up?  Is there a way to get the missing templates so that the GPO will apply to 21H2 properly?

Comment: @ΞένηΓήινος that link is broken.  Do you have another link or a search term I can use?

Comment: Try this [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=104042)